# How to handle files imported using __import__ in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Here's an example of the file-structure of my app, which I'm trying to turn into a standalone distributable one-dir application using `auto-py-to-exe`:

```
- plugins/file1.py
- plugins/file2.py
- plugins/...
- plugins/display/file1.py
- plugins/display/...
- main.py
- UI.py
```

The files which are under the `plugins` directory are dynamically imported using `__import__`. Here's the part of the code that does that:

```py
for plugin_filename in plugin_files[ plugin_path ]:
    plugin_file = plugin_filename.replace('.pye', '').replace('.py', '')
    plugin = __import__(plugin_file)
```

Of course, this doesn't get recognized by the Pyinstaller analysis and the plugin files don't get bundled into the exe. From the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) I've gathered that I need to use the `--hidden-import` option, so I tried this but with no success. This results in `ERROR: Hidden import not found`:
[image]

Is there any way I can add these files to the exe?

Comment: `plugins/file1` -> `plugins.file1`

Comment: I’m guessing I should add the path to the plugins folder to “paths” too?

Comment: You don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to solve this by adding the absolute path of the `plugins` folder to `paths` and adding `file1`, `file2`, etc. to the `—-hidden-import` option.

I also had to get rid of the if statement that checks if the file is a Python one and replaced that block with a loop that looks something like this:

```py
modules = [‘file1’, ‘file2’]
for module in modules:
    plugin = __import__(module)
```

Comment: This is unnecessary.